Cancellation of long term care insurance, return of certificate value
My wife and I have been paying premiums for long-term care insurance for the past 20 years or so. Total premiums paid between the two of us is approximately $60,000. The monthly premiums have been relatively steady over that time period. The premiums have been paid with after-tax funds.
We received letters today indicating a significant increase in premiums: 38% this year and each of the next two years.
We have a number of options: continue current coverage with the increased premiums, reduced benefits with the current premium or cancellation of the certificate of coverage.
Cancellation of the certificate would result in a payment to us of approximately $280,000 total, what I assume is the cash value of the certificates (representing the insurance company's current risk level for us). The insurance company has indicated that there may be a tax event with the cancellation option and has asked for identification information for a 1099 to be issued.
We feel we are able to self-insure for this risk but we are wondering what the tax event might be. Are we looking at ordinary income for the full amount, capital gains above what was paid in premiums or some other tax event?

Please update as to what you are going to do.  I feel this is very informative.

We have decided to cancel the current coverage as we're comfortable self-insuring. We will wait until 2025 to submit the paperwork as it's not due until March, 2025 and we don't want the tax even to occur this year. We were quite surprised about the payment option as it doesn't appear in the original certificate documentation regarding cancellation on our part. It was also originally sold as no increase in premiums, though no specific prohibition is in the certificate. This may be a compromise with California's department of insurance.


we are wondering what the tax event might be. Are we looking at ordinary income for the full amount, capital gains above what was paid in premiums or some other tax event?

Yes, you're looking at ordinary income under the IRC Sec. 61. Income is ordinary unless specified otherwise and there's no tax provision providing any special treatment for insurance surrender proceeds. Your basis is the premiums paid, anything in excess of that is ordinary income. It is not capital gains because a) the policy is not a capital asset, and b) surrender is not a sale or exchange (exchange of insurance policies is covered under IRC Sec. 1035).

Would it be possible to exchange the cash value towards a whole-life policy, annuity, or IRA? No idea if that's a better idea, just wondering if it's a possibility to avoid a taxable lump-sum payout since the OP's policy was purchased with post-tax money.

IRA probably not, whole-life/annuity probably yes (See IRC Sec. 1035). But avoiding lump-sum tax may not be the best of goals, need to discuss this with an insurance professional and a tax professional.
